# What web GIS is this? (And how can you tell?)

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, web-gis

I'm trying to understand a site that serves maps using a URL like this (URL de-coded):

```
http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/weave/server/request/execute.do?
crs=EPSG:3112&
mapengine.id=mapengine.ngis&
_OLSALT=0.48120216676034033&
request.id=com.cohga.GetMap&
request.format=json&
request.context={"core":{"entity":"ngis_bore"}}&
request.data={"map":{"layerids":[3,4,5,6,7,8,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,111,112],"extent":{"crs":"EPSG:3112","minx":-4846381.323291771,"miny":-5287521.9259454515,"maxx":4291040.883039461,"maxy":-1372651.4099949505},"scale":30890123.16326136},"image":{"type":{"returnType":"MIMEDATA"},"display":{"size":{"width":1118,"height":479}}}}
```

How can I work out if it's ESRI, GeoServer or something else? It doesn't seem to respond to `?service=wms&request=getCapabilities` (TomCat error). How can I interact with it?

Googling some of the terms like "mapengine" seems to lean towards ArcGIS: https://melb.cohga.com/wiki/display/weavedocs1/Map+Engine+ArcGIS

Comment: see _mapengine.id=mapengine.ngis_ - it might also be a product by [NGIS](http://www.ngis.com.au/) who used to write an application which sat on top of ArcIMS (I think). Can you share the page where you found the above request?

Comment: @StephenLead In this case NGIS stands for [National Groundwater Information System](http://www.bom.gov.au/water/groundwater/ngis/).  The NGIS product you are thinking of is [GeoSamba](http://www.geosamba.com/) by its partner [Indjii Systems](http://www.indji.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site looks like it has been built using the web mapping application builder software called [Weave by Cohga](http://www.cohga.com/products/26-weaveproduct):

> Weave is a business integration framework for rapidly combining
>   disparate information systems in an easy to use environment. It is
>   based on Open Systems technology and is independent from
>   vendor-specific technology and proprietary Application Programming
>   Interfaces (APIs).
>
> Weave is built using the Java platform so it can be installed on a
>   variety of hardware and operating systems such as Windows, Linux and
>   Unix.

I recognized the product and company name in the URL.

Comment: Hmm. So...how do you interact with it? It's "independent" of any well known standards? :p

Comment: Cohga have a Contact button on their website that should enable you to [get in touch](http://www.cohga.com/contact) with them.  However, I think the answer may be that you interact with the same underlying services as it does rather than with it.

Comment: Ok, heard back from them, yes, Weave is a layer that sits between (private) WMS layers and the outside world.